# How to fix keyboard layout bug in Sierra?

Tags: keyboard, bug, macos

Yesterday i had updated El Capitan to macOS Sierra on my Macbook Air 2015. But i had found a bug with changing keyboard layout. I have two keyboard layouts: US and Russian.

When i'm pressing CMD + Space shortcut, it is visually changing of keyboard layout, but actually sometimes keyboard layout is not changing, while not press ALT or CTRL or FN or SHIFT button, for example. How to fix that?

Comment: I have seen that, when cmd-tab to another application and back again, the layout refreshes. But it is really very annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a possible solution to this problem, I am not sure if it will work for you.

Instead of using the "next input source" shortcut, I use now the "previous input source" shortcut, and of course I swapped the keyboard bindings.

Hopefully this will work for you too.

Comment: Confirming, this fixed a bug for me!